# How can i make something like this in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I got this functionality with a slider, but I would like to make an extensible list just like in Microsoft office. But im not sure how to make it in xaml.
The only thing I can think of is Expander> but it looks different.

Comment: not Expander, it is a ComboBox

Comment: OMG, who voted this as off topic. It's not best formulated question, but it is not off topic.

Comment: Is there any book/course without introducing to basic (standard) wpf controls?

Comment: Book/course about what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean

```
<ComboBox>
   <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

resp:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" />
```

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for. thanks, my english needs more improvements, i formulated as good as i can :)

Comment: It's not about the english. Nobody will blame you for english. It's about describing the problem. Instead of "this", and "it" you could describe what you want. For example: I want to let user to select text size, like in the picture, but I cannot find such control. It's definitívny easier to understand than "it",especialle when your english is not perfect :)